# Windows updates through local GPO - Optional updates

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, group-policy, windows-update

We have automated the deployment of Windows updates on our servers through the use of local GPO. Everything works great and a screenshot of the existing configuration can be found in the screenshot attached below.

[Local GPO Windows Updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4wOr.png)

We have noticed though, that Optional Updates are being ignored, not installed automatically and need manual intervention. Is there any way, either Microsoft official or a registry hack to force the installation of the Optional Updates as well?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You comment that you do not use WSUS due to them not being on the domain.  You can configure clients directly via the registry to use a specified WSUS server and set them to automatically install updates if desired.  GPOs ease the automation, but are not requirements.  Scheduled tasks are one of many ways to set a specified time to install if you're up to the scripting.

The relevant registry keys:

```
HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate
HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU
```

From TechNet: **"Configure Automatic Updates in a Non–Active Directory Environment"** on these keys and what goes under them:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708449(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Updated answer with TechNet article link and registry keys directly.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not using a WSUS server. Usually, optional updates are approved via WSUS and pushed via GPO scheduling. You have selected Recommended Updates so that won't be a problem.

Microsoft says optional updates can only be installed manually.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you are right, we are not using a WSUS server in this scenario as these machines are not part of a domain, so I am assuming there is no other way to be done.